# Is there a better greeting than 'Dear John, et al'?

Tags: letter

I'm writing a letter (electronically) to accept an invitation extended by a group of people (open source project). The invitation itself was written by a single person (say 'John'), but on behalf of the group.  I'm requested to respond to the entire group (by way of a private email list).

For all practical purposes, the group has an uncountable number of individuals, so it's not an option to list them all. Moreover, I don't know, and can't know, who they all are.

The tone I intend is formal, but not stand-offish.

What's the best way to open my letter?

Is there something more appropriate than this?

> Dear John, et al.

Comment: Good morning / afternoon / evening (as applicable). Polite and professional.

Comment: Not very applicable when writing to people in multiple time zones... or maybe if it's unknown when the letter will be read.

Comment: Doesn't matter when it's read, it's about when it's written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that using French could come off as a bit cheeky or have the wrong connotations. Rather, you should use one of the standard formal email openings:

> Dear All,
>
> To whom it may concern,
>
> Hi All, (slightly informal)

Or...

You can just go straight into the information, which is what I would do. I think it depends on the context of your email though.

> Subject - Boilerplate Code.

Make a subject for your email as above. Then go straight in:

> I have prepared the better half of the boilerplate code,
>
> Best regards,
>
> (name)

I have done this before in a formal email to a group and it has been okay.

Overall, it depends on the situation. Decide what would work best.

I hope this helped.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that comes from Latin, not French.  But point taken. Thank you.